# vitest test coverage does not fail when threshold is not met

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, vite, vitest

i want my test coverage to fail if the thresholds are not met

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  test: {
    environment: "happy-dom",
    exclude: [...configDefaults.exclude, "**/tests/e2e/*"],
    coverage: {
      reporter: ['text', 'json', 'html'],
      lines: 80,
      functions: 80,
      branches: 80,
      statements: 80,
    }
  },
```

even though i get the error message, it still shows pass

```
File                    | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files               |     100 |    33.33 |     100 |     100 |                   
 components/base/button |     100 |    33.33 |     100 |     100 |                   
  Button.vue            |     100 |    33.33 |     100 |     100 | 36-53             
 config                 |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  index.ts              |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
ERROR: Coverage for branches (33.33%) does not meet global threshold (80%)

 PASS  Waiting for file changes...
       press h to show help, press q to quit
```

any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are seeing this in 2024 and using vitest@1.x.x the previous solution won't work for you.`thresholds` should be an object instead.
See code below:

```js
{
  test: {
    ...your other configurations
    coverage: {
      ...your other configurations
      thresholds: {
        lines: 80,
        functions: 80,
        branches: 80,
        statements: 80
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See documentation here: [coverage.thresholds[glob-pattern]](https://vitest.dev/config/#coverage-thresholds-glob-pattern)

Answer (score 2):

I think mine works, I'm sharing my vite config file, hope it helps you:

```js
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url';
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import type { UserConfig as VitestUserConfigInterface } from 'vitest/config';

const vitestConfig: VitestUserConfigInterface = {
  test: {
    watch: false,
    include: ['**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,mts,cts,jsx,tsx}'],
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    reporters: ['verbose'],
    coverage: {
      include: ['src/**/*'],
      exclude: [
        'src/main.ts',
        'src/plugins/',
        'src/App.vue',
        'src/shims-vue.d.ts',
        'src/router/*',
        'src/stores/*',
        'src/types/*',
        'src/components/icons/*'
      ],
      reporter: ['text', 'json', 'html'],
      all: true,
      lines: 80,
      functions: 80,
      branches: 80,
      statements: 80
    }
  }
};

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  // https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1149#issuecomment-857686209
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd());
  const envWithProcessPrefix = Object.entries(env).reduce(
    (prev, [key, val]) => {
      const [, keyNoVite] = key.split('VITE_');
      return {
        ...prev,
        ['process.env.' + key]: `"${val}"`,
        ['process.env.' + keyNoVite]: `"${val}"`
      };
    },
    {}
  );

  return {
    define: envWithProcessPrefix,
    test: vitestConfig.test,
    resolve: {
      alias: { '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)) }
    },
    plugins: [vue()]
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running tests in watch mode (**Waiting for file changes**...)

Use this command to run without watch mode: `vitest run`

Or if you want to run with watch mode **ON** use: `vitest watch`

Comment: yeah, the Pass indicator is not more there when i run without watch mode, but is there a way to fail the test coverage if the threshold is not met?. like to have a fail indicator

Comment: I think what you are trying to achieve doesn't make much sense. Watch mode is meant for development where developers are trying to fix failing tests. If test would fail (exit) when it any test fails in watch mode it would mean just a bad DX.